# InAppBrowser plugin Authentication

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an **Ionic 2** app made to view *.pdf* files on a server where **authentication** with a cookie is required.
I want to use the **InAppBrowser** plugin with Ionic Native to do it.
Does the opened page keep your cookies to keep you authenticated ?
And if not, how can I view *.pdf* files authenticated ?

Comment: Did you succeed to open InAppBrowser with authentication?